# DB2 to postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want migration from DB2 to Postgres in the shell. How can i change to connection sql from db2 to Postgres .

```
#!/bin/bash
DBUSRSTR="user ${DBUSER} using ${DBPSW}"

VAR=`db2 CONNECT TO ${DBNAME} ${DBUSRSTR}`
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  logErr ${MSG002E}
  logErr ${VAR}
  exit 2
fi

db2 set current schema TEST
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  logErr ${MSG002E}
  exit 2
fi
logInfo "Set Current Schema:" $?


db2 truncate table TEST.table1 immediate
```

I just want to remove the db2 command and change to the Postgres command.

Answer (score 1):

You may run the psql command line and execute a query.

```
psql -d ${DBNAME}  -U  ${DBUSER} -h ${DBHOST} -c "select 1"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you give me a sample to change to code from DB2 to postgres?

Comment: for these soruce code . "#!/bin/bash
DBUSRSTR="user ${DBUSER} using ${DBPSW}"

VAR=`db2 CONNECT TO ${DBNAME} ${DBUSRSTR}`
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  logErr ${MSG002E}
  logErr ${VAR}
  exit 2
fi

db2 set current schema TEST
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  logErr ${MSG002E}
  exit 2
fi
logInfo "Set Current Schema:" $?


db2 truncate table TEST.table1 immediate"

Comment: @guoleili : your db2 code is truncating a table in a schema. Use the appropriate code in Postgres by connecting to the relevant schema. We can't give you a working code as we don't have your environment. You'll have to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot maintain an open PostgreSQL connection across several client invocations, but you can use a “here document”:

```sh
psql -U user <<EOF
    SET ...
    TRUNCATE ...
    ...
EOF
```

For the password, you'd use a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html).